# Convert a view to a table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Given:

`Daily(t)` - a table containing events from day `t` (mutable only during day `t`)

`Agg(t)` - a table containing an aggregation of all historical events till day `t` (immutable after day `t`)

During day `t`, while `Daily(t)` is still mutable, I define the view `V_Agg(t)` as follows:

`V_Agg(t)=q(Agg(t-1), Daily(t))` - (`q` being the aggregating query)

Since `Daily(t)` does not change after day `t`, when day `t` ends, I would like to "materialize" `V_Agg(t)`, turning it to `Agg(t)` for `V_Agg(t+1)` to work with.

While implementing this process, I figured that having `Agg(t)` and `Daily(t)` is actually enough. I can have `Agg(t)` as a view during day `t`, and at some point during day `t` (doesn't matter when), I can replace the now immutable view `Agg(t-1)` with a table named the same (`Agg(t-1)`).

This would spare me the need to maintain `V_Agg(t)` and in general would be more stable (I can create `Agg(t)` independently from the process that turns `Agg(t-1)` from a view to a table).

However, I could not find a way to write a table over a view with the same name. Trying so gives a `... is not allowed for this operation because it is currently a VIEW.`

Is this solution possible in a transactional manner (without deleting the view in one step and creating the table instead)? If so - how?

Comment: Why do you need a table for each day? Maybe I'm missing something, but can you just have two date partitioned tables and then a view (whose definition you update each day) that unions data from both?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I didn't like the semantics of the view with updating definitions, as I would either have to time the view definition switch at exactly the day change (not feasible / stable), or define it as an aggregation of `Agg(t)` and `All Daily tables after day t`, which almost duplicates the `Agg` logic instead of reusing it. Regarding partitioned tables for `Daily` and `Agg`, if I find a good solution for the switching views, you are right. I thought of partitions as technically equivalent in this case, and hoped it was more non BQ specific to explain the design with daily tables.

Comment: Also, date partitioning `Agg(t)` isn't as important, as it isn't likely to be queried across days. Date partitioning `Daily(t)` indeed makes a lot of sense.